# React CORS issue with firebase even though rule is set to true

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cors

I am 99% sure that i set the rules correctly for my firebase realtime database.
React-Redux is used for by both react app that call the firebase
However the problem is quite puzzling,
1) I created a new react app and try to do an axios POST/GET to the firebase but CORS error keep happening

2) I used my old react app and call the same API as (1) no CORS error and the POST request went through.

3) I test that the API works using postman, both POST and GET request went through

4) I also verified that localhost was allowed in the permission setting under domain for firebase

Anyone got any idea what is wrong?

error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://...firebaseio./Employee.json'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response
>   is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

```
employee.js:42 Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:80)
```

Comment: Have you tried performing the XMLHttpRequest *without* credentials by setting the `withCredentials` attribute to `false`?

Comment: The error message says *“The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is ''”*. That’s the specific problem you need to fix.

Comment: @jered solution solved the issue for me. However, previously when i use firebase to setup redux in react, i didn't add WithCredentials and the HTTP request still went through. Hm.. food for thoughts... Thanks jered for the solution!